# how to submit data from summernote using ajax to springboot backend

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, summernote

```
<form id="videoIDs" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div id="summernote" name="summernote"></div>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" onclick="submitFunction()"
            value="Download" />
</form>
```

I want to submit the text which people type in the summernote, this is the html code.

```
<script>
    $('#summernote').summernote({
        placeholder : 'hi, visitor',
        tabsize : 2,
        height : 250,
        airMode : false,
        focus : true,
    });

    function submitFunction() {
        var formData = new FormData();
        formData.append("files", $('#summernote').summernote('code'));
        alert(formData.get('files'));
        $.ajax({
            type : 'post',
            url : '/l10n/brightcove/test',
            data : formData,
            processData : false,
            contentType : false,
        })
    }
</script>
```

I use Ajax to post the text content.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/test", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody String uploadFile(@RequestParam(name = "files") MultipartFile file,
        HttpServletRequest request) {

    String fileName = file.getOriginalFilename();
    System.out.println("size:" + file.getSize());
```

but the method shows that the file I received is a 0 size file,it really makes me confuse because when I click submit button,I can see the text in the summernote alert.

Is there anything wrong in my code?

This is the output log.

```
2018-12-14 11:41:20.833  WARN 56184 --- [nio-8080-exec-7] .w.s.m.s.DefaultHandlerExceptionResolver : Resolved [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.MissingServletRequestPartException: Required request part 'files' is not present]
size:0
```

Comment: what is the type of file parameter? it seems file is missing.

Comment: System.out.println("type:" + file.getContentType());                                      output:  type:application/octet-stream                                                                                do you mean this type?